# Directory Permissions

Tags: permissions

I have the following directory structure:

```
rodrigo@LabGeM:/home/labgem/renameSeq$ ls -al
total 1484
drwxrwxrwx  3 root   root      4096 Mai 16 08:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 31 labgem labgem    4096 Mai 16 09:07 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root     16624 Mai 16 08:39 Map.xlsx
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root     38152 Mai 14 14:14 .renameSeq
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root   1436011 Mai 14 13:39 renameSeqBasics.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        44 Mai 16 07:37 renameSeq.sh
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root      4096 Mai 16 07:42 Seq
```

I need the parent directory `renameSeq` to be "undeletable" by any other user but root, as his original content (shown above). But I need any user to be able to create , delete and modify new files inside the parent directory and `Seq` directory as well.
I've been playing with sticky bit, chmod and chown, but with no success. Normally the parent directory won't allow the creation of new files inside it. Is there a simple way to do it or will I have to use something like the discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869536/linux-directory-permissions-read-write-but-not-delete)?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: It may sound a bit complecated at start, but is really quite simple. I'll try to describe it some details, it will take a moment, though.

Comment: You have to remember about one thing - surprisingly related to your issue - everything in Unix/Linux is a file. That means also that your renameSeq directory is also a file, file that contains information about its contents as directory. Now, if you make your renameSeq read only, that will affect rather its content. Now - if you make root owner of your renameSeq you make only root able to modify renameSeq and it's content. But - here's the tricky part - the same rules apply to renameSeq as subdirectory of labgem. renameSeq is "described" in labgem file/directory. So now...

Comment: Since labgem directory allows labgem user to modify its contents - you may be able to remove your renameSeq directory as labgem, as long as it's empty - if it's contents belong to someone else, that may prevent removal. Now what's important for you is to set proper permissions at a proper part in your path.

Comment: Where you allow only root (or other user) to modify the subdirs contents, but still allowing other users to enter it and create files/dirs inside of it, if needed. Personally I'd say that for what you want to do, I wouldn't even create a user (like labgem) , just group (can be labgem) - owner of the directory tree then can be root, but group owner can be labgem. Then you set group permissions as required on the level you want it for those users who belong to group labgem. And at some level of that tree you basically disallow the whole group remove/create anything, leaving this permission...

Comment: ...only to root (well, or other owner - if you still want it). Bear in mind also, that users need also permissions to traverse the whole path to their files. So all permissions on the way have to be set properly. Now - one more thing - if you want to make sure that all files/dirs created by different users have proper group owner, not the creators one - you can use sgid on the directory where you want them to create their stuff. This will help you avoid issues with files readable for creator but inaccessible for the rest. However maybe not a direct answer to your issue, I hope this will...

Comment: shed some light on the subject, helping you resolving your troubles.

Comment: On the side of it, however most likely not needed here - in some more complicated scenarios you may also consider using ACL's. Also - if you want some file really untouchable, preventing it from removal even by root (may be useful sometimes), until unset, you can use immutable attribute (chattr +i file). Anyway, for now, review your scenario and thinkg about what exactly you'd like to achieve and then build a proper structure of dirs, with proper ownerships and permissions on each level. Good luck!

Comment: It's me again - actually just found out what I missed earlier - if you want only one file not removable inside another, in which otherwise you want users to be able to create other dirs/files - yes, setting +a attribute may also be an idea. Looking yet once again at your files permissions - I'd rather avoid setting rwx for all users, very bad practice from security perspective.

Comment: @Jacek Thank you very much. I will follow your advice with all that you exposed here in mind and consider the best strategy for my "files". I must say I loved the way you answered my question, will be useful not just for this one thing. Regrads.

Comment: Since you seem to be in that comfortable situation where you're building the whole structure from scratch (more or less?) you can basically do this fairly good with just generic Unix file permissions/ownership, to keep it nice and simple. However sometimes, in some scenarios, where really some users have to gain access to some other owner's (both users/groups) - then yes, ACLs may be required - but that involves pretty much another level of permissions, which you and your fellow users/admins have to remember about, since they may not be easily visible with the usual ls commands. Cheers.

Comment: Indeed another level, not my level for now. :P. @Jacek If you with, you may post it all as an aswer, it will be a pleasure to mark it as chosen answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo - that's not a problem, don't need points. Happy if I can help with my knowledge. Cheers